# Error in Installing Laravel 5.7 on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, server, installation, laravel-5.7

I am new to Laravel, I am trying to install Laravel 5.7 on ubuntu Server using terminal. But I am getting the following error

> Installing laravel/laravel (v5.7.0)
>     - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.7.0)
>       Downloading: 100%
>
> Created project in pmc You made a reference to a non-existent script
>   @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"

After the above, the installation stops. I am PHP 7.2 installed on the ubuntu server.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`sudo apt-get remove composer
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '669656bab3166a7aff8a7506b8cb2d1c292f042046c5a994c43155c0be6190fa0355160742ab2e1c88d40d5be660b410') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer`